# Alfresco Integrate with Kofax

Tags: ocr, alfresco, kofax

is there any quick way to integrate Alfresco community version with kofax? have searched documents but only paid versions are discussed.

Target: scanner scan form > place in certain space in Alfresco > kick off Kofax script to OMR / OCR the content and convert into data > kick off another scripts for other possibilities.

any advice are welcome. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Kofax CMIS connector you don't need a specialized release-script.

Here is some extra info about the connector:
https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwieoOmy093JAhWHsxQKHXVTB6QQFggoMAE&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.kofax.com%2Fpub%2Fsupport%2Fexport-connectors%2Fkofax-supported%2Fdocumentation%2Fcmis%2Fkofaxexportconnectorforcmisadministratorsguide_en.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHw7osn2m6pXihuVoWDUuv1X6xnTg